# Executing Love2D scripts

Tags: love2d

The only way I found out to execute my script with the Love2d framework is to zip all of it and then rename the zip to love.  This kinds of take a lot of time for a small modification.  Is there a faster way to do it?  I tried to command line and I get this error

```
'love' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 5):

LÖVE also executes folders if they have the main.lua in them - you can just drag and drop the folder onto the application, or call it from the command line with the folder as the argument if you prefer.

Comment: On Windows, it's referred to as `love.exe` for command prompt purposes. You'll need to be in the directory the executable is stored in, though.

Answer (score 4):

LÖVE runs the contents of a folder if it can find a main.lua in it (Like Bill said).
[Note that it doesn't check subfolders].

There are three ways to run a love2D program, you can:

**a) Drag the folder over the love.exe binary/link (This works in Win and *Nix, I don't know about OS X).**

**b) Navigate to the directory that is one level above the folder and type  `love [folder containing main.lua]`**

or

**c) Zip it up and rename the .zip to a .love. Then double click the .love file**

---

#### Option 'b' will fail if the binary is not in the `%PATH%`(Windows) or `$PATH`(*Nix) variable

(It will spout an error message like `'love' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` on windows and `bash: love: command not found` on linux).

***There are two ways to solve this:***
(Both require ADMIN/root privileges, )
1) Add the love binary to the `PATH` variable. Here's how to do this [in windows](https://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=9372#p57980) and [in linux](http://home.ubalt.edu/abento/linux/terminal/addtopath.html) (In linux you want to do something like this: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/where/ever/you/put/love/`)

2) You can add a link to the love2D binary in `C:\WINDOWS\system32` or `/usr/bin/`.
In windows you create a shortcut to the love.exe (wherever you installed it to) and then drag it into C:\WINDOWS\system32. In linux you can run this:
`sudo link /path/to/love/binary /usr/bin/love && sudo chmod ugo+rwx /usr/bin/love`

I hope this helps!

Sources: 
Google (the links above), Love2D and my knowledge :D

Answer (score 2):

simple way:

- create folder /path/to/Game
- put your files (main.lua, conf.lua, ...) in folder /path/to/Game

you can run script like this:

```
love /path/to/Game/
```

or if you use Linux, you can go in folder (cd /path/to/Game) and type just:

```
love .
```

(dot means that you want to run it form in folder

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be very helpful when i started. Hope this helps

[A Guide to Getting Started With Love2d](http://nova-fusion.com/2011/06/14/a-guide-to-getting-started-with-love2d/)

Comment: It has what you have to do to be able to run the love command

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Mac OS, you should run using:

```
open -a love xxx.love
```

To recreate a file as .love, you can run in command line:

```
zip xxx.love file1.lua file2
```

If you just want to replace a file in .love:

```
zip -r xxx.love file1.lua
```

I think this will make your work easier.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution for save time.
You have to create a file **.bat** with this simple command:

```
del Project.love
7z.exe a Project.zip ..\Project\*
ren Project.zip Project.love
```

For do this you need to download 7zip and insert this file (file.bat) into the folder of your project. Like this:

[image: Example]

Good work!

Answer (score 0):

If you're yousing Notepad++ to write your code, just open your main.lua file, then go to Run and add there this text including quotes:

```
"Path" "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
```

Where Path is a Full path to love.exe.
The save it to a key combination and now you can test your code by using this combination in any script at Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sublime Text, you can make a build which runs your application.
https://love2d.org/wiki/Sublime_Text

While in Sublime Text press CMD + B or Ctrl + B